# Openshift 2.4 cdk Gitlab-CE "SchedulerPredicates failed due to PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "gitlab-ce-redis-data", which is unexpected."

Tags: openshift, gitlab, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

After spinning up the newest cdk v 2.4 (https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/download/), I get the following when trying to deploy gitlab-ce, per gitlab's directions at https://about.gitlab.com/2016/06/28/get-started-with-openshift-origin-3-and-gitlab/

```
Time    Kind and Name   Reason and Message
2:21:21 PM  
Pod
gitlab-ce-redis-1-1digf 
Failed scheduling  
*SchedulerPredicates failed due to PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "gitlab-ce-redis-data", which is unexpected.*
6 times in the last minute
2:21:20 PM  
Pod
gitlab-ce-1-89qc8   
Failed scheduling  
SchedulerPredicates failed due to PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "gitlab-ce-etc", which is unexpected.
6 times in the last minute
2:21:19 PM  
Pod
gitlab-ce-postgresql-1-yatd9    
Failed scheduling  
SchedulerPredicates failed due to PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "gitlab-ce-postgresql", which is unexpected.
```

They seem to be getting created and stuck in a "Pending" states:

```
NAME                   STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE
gitlab-ce-data         Pending                                      5d
gitlab-ce-etc          Pending                                      5d
gitlab-ce-postgresql   Pending                                      5d
gitlab-ce-redis-data   Pending                                      5d
```

How can I troubleshoot these errors with creating pv's?

Answer (score 0):

PVs needs to be created by admin user, so log in as admin

```
oc login -u system:admin
```

You may use a token for the previous step if master is a remote host. Then just create the PV:

```
$cat pv.yaml

kind: PersistentVolume
  metadata:
    name: foobar
  spec:
    capacity:
      storage: 5Gi
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
    hostPath:
      path: /tmp/foo



oc create pv -f pv.yaml
```

The `Retain`, `ReadWriteMany`, `5Gi` values may be different in your case. Check the [docs](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/persistent_volumes.html). 'hostPath' works only in single-node cluster, otherwise you need to use NFS or similar.

Comment: so I tried manually deleting and recreating the PVCs, but I seem to get the same result - PVCs are created but stuck in "Pending"

Comment: You need to create PVs, not PVCs